# How can I scale the numbers on the y-axis in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file that looks like this:

```
0 "A" 1306051 1265532 736392 1359570 1295778
1 "B" 1384727 1335463 814167 1436868 1370715
```

I use this command to plot the data

```
plot for [n=3:7] '$data_file' using 1:n:xticlabel(2) title column
```

I'd like to divide the numbers on the y-axis by one million, but I do not know how to do this. I do not want to change my data file. I assume I have to change something in the using part of the command or I have to use the gnuplot format command, but I could not figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for my

```
plot for [n=3:7] '$data_file' using 1:n:xticlabel(2) thru x/1e6 title column
```

found it [there](http://astroa.physics.metu.edu.tr/MANUALS/gnuplot_manual/3.5/node6.html)

Comment: Note, that the `thru` option is deprecated since long time and will be removed from future gnuplot versions. Use the following statement instead: `plot for [n=3:7] '$data_file' using 1:(column(n)/1e6):xtic(2) title column`.